# To move the text to next line if it is saved with clicking enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

Now here is what i want,I have a form in which  there is a field called narration.It is a textarea field.When i write something inside that and hit enter it goes to new line in the field itself.Now when i save that in database, it is saved as it is.Now I am trying to retrieve that data from database inside a table.
So what i want is that if the retrieved data was saved as three lines then those three lines should be displayed in three table rows in that column.
I think i can explain better using a fiddle.I want something like as it is in the below fiddle.the data in 3 rows of column particulars is from the field narration from a single row in database.I know it is tough to explain what exactly i am looking for,but i have tried my best to let you know.If you need any additional details let me know please.

here is the narration textarea-I want to display every new line in new table row as you can see in the fiddle.
[image]

It should look something like this-
https://jsfiddle.net/9bgkw472/1/

But it is looking like this
[image: but it is looking like this]
Thanks in advance.

This is the table code where particular column value is retrieved from database field narration-

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Sr.no.
          </th>
            <th >
              Particulars
          </th>
            <th>
              Type
          </th>
          <th>
            Amount
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td id="particulars"><textarea  id="narpreview" name="narpreview"  autocomplete="off" readonly ></textarea></td>
        <td>Net Purchases</td>
        <td > <input id="netpreview" name="netpreview"  readonly /></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Vat</td>
        <td> <input id="vatpreview" name="vatpreview"  readonly /></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cst</td>
        <td> <input id="cstpreview" name="cstpreview"  readonly /></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Service Tax</td>
        <td> <input id="serpreview" name="serpreview"  readonly /></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Other charges</td>
        <td> <input id="othpreview" name="othpreview"  readonly /></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
         <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total amount</td>
        <td> <input id="totpreview" name="totpreview"  readonly /></td>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

This is how the data is retrieved from the database into table field-

```
 $("#savep").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

       formData = $('form.pform').serialize() + '&' 
        + encodeURI($(this).attr('name'))
        + '='
        + encodeURI($(this).attr('value'));

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "demopost.php",
               data: formData,
               success: function(response){
           $('#dp3,#nar').val('');

            if (response.success) 
               $('#narpreview').val(response.nar);
                           } else {
                alert("failure in");
            }
        },
               error: function(){
                alert("failure out");
               }
           });
     });
```

Comment: This is all great, but exactly how does this data look when it's returned from the DB ?

Comment: replace `\n` with `<br>` in the strings

Comment: it looks like the image below fiddle @adeneo

Comment: well i am not even entering \n anywhere @charlietfl

Comment: If you want each line to be in different row then why you don't use input instead of textarea and add new row when user hit enter using `$('input').keypress(function(e) { if (e.which == 13) { } });`?

Comment: That image says nothing about the data ?

Comment: yes you are when you create new line in textarea by hitting `enter`....it is not visible, but it is there in that string

Comment: you can see the particular field in which there is a textarea and it contains the data retrieved from the database,so i want each new line to be in next table row @adeneo

Comment: @charlietfl..can you please tell me how do i replace \n with <br> ?

Comment: if it needs to be in new table row `<br>.` won't work anyway. We don't know how table is going to be generated so question is too broad anyway. but you can split the text to array at `\n`

Comment: @charlietfl..i have already mentioned that table is already present when the page loads and only the data from database is retrieved into its field.

Comment: @charlietfl..for you i have edited the code and added the code by which the data is retrieved into particular's field in table